# How to only allow '0's and '1's to be put into a textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I've found many ways to restrict users from typing alphabetical characters, but I want to be more specific. I'm making a binary calculator and I would like the user to only be able to fill in the numbers '0' and '1'.

Comment: `onkeydown "if (key != 0) && (key != 1) then disallow"`, so to speak?

Comment: What type of application are you talking about?

Comment: VB Windows Forms Application, using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @MarcB - so, if they copy and paste non-binary in, that's fine?

Comment: @damien: still have to filter after-the-fact.

Comment: @MarcB - that's why I'd argue for a simpler approach where you just apply the after-the-fact filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied in textbox_keypress event ..

```
Private Sub txtbox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtbox.KeyPress 
  Dim k As Byte = Asc(e.KeyChar)    

  If Not (e.KeyChar = "0" Or e.KeyChar = "1" Or k = 8 Or k = 13) Then e.Handled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you, although I'd like the user to be able to use backspace as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are MANY ways to do this, I like this method:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim valid_values As String = "01"
    If Not valid_values.Contains(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is most maintainable among suggested answers, IMHO. +1

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure the key pressed is either 0 or 1. Otherwise it will act as if no keys were pressed.

```
Private Sub txtBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtBox.KeyDown

If Not (e.KeyCode = Keys.0 OR e.KeyCode = Keys.1) Then
   e.Handled = True
EndIf 

End Sub
```